windows turn ND OFF FEATURE
i disabled my Microsoft hyper v, windows hypervisor platform, windows subsystem for Linux and my virtual machine platform and then I enabled it back but now I cannot access any of my servers on putty and ubuntu but I cant when I login to my proxmox virtual environment on my browser, what is the issue and what should I do. I have tried everything, still no progress. im  using ubuntu 22.04

Question needs details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

ive done that now
